# ¿ es correcto insertar valores a un atributo con muchos valores?

Tags: mysql

```
create table autores(
idAutor int auto_increment key,
nombre varchar(50) not null
```

);

```
insert into autores(nombre) values ('juanito perez, Juan Carlos, Carlos Pinto');
```

hola tengo una duda es normal insertar varios valores a un atributo a tabla autores(nombre), se agradece la ayuda

Comment: no estas ingresando varios valores.. el valor es uno solo, es una cadena que contiene 3 nombres separados por una coma.. pero el valor, es uno solo....

Comment: entonces mejor seria hacer 3 insert respectivos?, es q despues tengo q mostrarlo en un select  en otra tabla libro ,es q quiero q aparezcan los 3 autores

Comment: Entonces cada autor deberia estar en una fila no.. entendes que eso no mete 3 registros, si no uno solo con un string grande???

Comment: gracias a todos por ayudar se agradece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no es correcto ese query. Con ese insert estas agregando un único registro con la cadena **"juanito perez, Juan Carlos, Carlos Pinto"**
Lo que podrías hacer es ajustar el insert a esta forma:

```
INSERT INTO autores(nombre)
VALUES
    ('juanito perez'),
    ('Juan Carlos'),
    ('Carlos Pinto');
```

Comment: vale pa, no me acordaba mucho como era ,  se agradece mucho amigo  saludos!!